# Sharing SQL data through Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, database-connection, shared

I was hoping to get help to find a solution.
I have an excel spreadsheet that connects to my SQL server and populates a spreadsheet based on a query i have written.
I want to share this spreadsheet with 10 users.
This is were the problem comes. In order to share the spreadsheet i have to remove the link. Meaning the connection to the SQL data is lost.
The database is frequently updated so need to keep the connection live. All 10 users might be in the spreadsheet at the same time working on cases. 
Is there a way for me to do this as iv search high and low and cant find a solution. I am almost tempted to create a c# app that will allow me to do this instead of using a spreadsheet, Any suggestions will be very much welcomed 
Thanks

Comment: For a variety of reasons, your idea about creating a c# app is a good one.

Comment: Thanks Dan i think it will have to be the route i go down

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://cirkulate.com. We are working on such a service that enables developers to go from SQL to automatically refreshing spreadsheets.

You'll only need to specify SQL that populate the cells, the refresh schedule(optional) and the recipient email addresses.

When the spreadsheet refreshes, all the recipients get the latest copy of the spreadsheet along with a snapshot of the spreadsheet in the email body, so they consume a quick snapshot within the email client.

Disclosure: Just to be clear about affiliations, I am the founder of Cirkulate.

Comment: You must *clearly* disclose your affiliation ***in the post*** when linking to your own products or projects. Otherwise, your posts may be treated as “astro-turfing” or spam.